# css reference for all kind of layouts?

Tags: css

dont want to use css frameworks like 960 cause that will lock the width.

and using dreamweaver will just add a lot of noise css.

would be good if there was a good css layout reference website with the common layouts and describing how to code that with css manipulating divs, so you dont have to figure it out yourself by experiments.

eg.

```
 header, content, right sidebar, footer
 header, left sidebar, content, right sidebar, footer
 header, content, rightsidebar, another rightsidebar, footer
```

and so on.

havent been able to find such a resource, would be great if someone could recommend such pages. thanks.

Comment: Ther is a fluid version of 960gs... And both blueprint and 960 have generators for custom grid sizes... Just FYI :-)

Comment: does blueprint got a fluid equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you decide *not* to use a time-tested framework,  you potentially create more problems than you solve. That being said, I would encourage one of the two [960](http://960.gs) derivatives:

1. [fluid](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)
2. [elastic](http://csswizardry.com/typogridphy/)

Comment: would you recommend blueprint or is 960 easier to use? if so, which one of the above derivates would you recommend?

Comment: I've only used 960, and I've found it to be very easy, and very clean.

Comment: i've looked into their custom grid generator. and you can generate like 100 columns if you want to. so you are not limited to 24? a lot of persons say that you are limited to 16, then they say they got a 24 column version? but as i see it, you are not limited to any of those now with the custom generator? so why do they all talk about 16, 24 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A List Apart has several good articles about creating liquid multi-column layouts with CSS:

- [Multi-Column Layouts Climb Out of the Box](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/)
- [In Search of the Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/)

They have a bunch more.  This is just what I found after a quick search.

Comment: +1 I'd recommend reading A List Apart in general.

Answer (score 1):

Something like Matthew James Taylor's [Ultimate 3 column holy grail](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm) template? It should have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is [Glish](http://www.glish.com/css/).